# There is no "id' in the html? What could i do instead of an 'find_element_by_id"

Tags: python, selenium

[html code i am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wUOD.png)

I am trying make a bot for auto sign in but there is no "id" in the website html for me to use.
I was wondering if there might be an alternative solution to instead of finding element by "id"

```
password = browser.find_element_by_id("no id") 
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
```

Comment: are you using selenium? @Cameron

Update: Oops just read you are :) I will post my answer in a moment

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath in this case.

```
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']") 
password.click()
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you use `find_element_by_xpath()` and from chrome get the full xpath of the element:

**right_click->copy->copy full xpath**

Answer (score 0):

Selenium offers a lot of methods to get elements, as [stated by the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#locate-elements-by).

- CLASS_NAME = 'class name'
- CSS_SELECTOR = 'css selector'
- ID = 'id'
- LINK_TEXT = 'link text'
- NAME = 'name'
- PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = 'partial link text'
- TAG_NAME = 'tag name'
- XPATH = 'xpath'

[In the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) there are some use case examples.